# How to make JScrollBar to scroll?

Tags: java, swing, jscrollbar

I am working on a project in Netbeans for which I need to use a scrollbar (Swing controls). I have added the same in the `JFrame` but it is not scrolling. I don't know what is the code to be given to make it scrollable and under which event. I'm new to Java and I would be very grateful if somebody could help and give me the answer.

[UI DESIGN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQspa.png)

Comment: More helpful than a screenshot (which could be described as 'lots of controls with a scrollbar on the right') would be a [mre]. Note though that nowhere in the question do you mention a `JScrollPane` which is the component you should be focusing on. See [How to Use Scroll Panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) in the tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Try to  take a `Panel` and add components to that `Panel` and set the `JScrollPane` to that panel and add that to your `Frame`.

```
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(yourPanel);
yourFrame.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Better to add the `scrollpane` to the **CENTER**, so that it will get all the space available to yourFrame.